# Creating Pre-Made CSS Variables With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say I'm working on a large page. I want to predefine some CSS styles as variables in JavaScript that I can use later. Is it possible? What would the syntax be?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var box = document.querySelector('.box'); 
var styleColor = style.color;
var red = "red"

box.onclick = function(){styleColor.red;}
```

I'm aware you can do it like this:

```
var box = document.querySelector('.box');

box.onclick = function(){box.style.color = "red";}
```

But I want to cache the CSS so It can be re-used later. Is this possible, if so what would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 1):

Write your `css` in a normal css file. For instance:

```
.myRedClass { color: red; }
```

Then append a class to elements you want to be red in javascript as follows

```
var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
element.className += " " + "myRedClass";
```